# Use different example values for parameters in Swagger 2?

Tags: documentation, swagger, swagger-2.0

I have an API that uses the same definition in more than 1 place, but I want to include different examples for the different places.

To give some context, I have:

```
parameters:
- in: body
  description: The user object for the new user
  name: body
  schema:
    "$ref": "#/definitions/User"
```

Which uses the User object.  The User object is also returned when a user signs in, and contains more information than what is used to create the user, for example, the user id.

I have an example on the definition, but is there a way I can have a separate example for the POST /user endpoint body parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest having two different objects for the user: `UserCreate` which is for creating (and perhaps updating) and `UserDetail` which is returned by post/put/get with full detail. This allows for different examples as you can see below.

You can have `UserDetail` inherit all the properties from `UserCreate` by using the `allOf` construct. In this example, they share name and email and `UserDetail` has an additional id and href property:

```
paths:
  /users:
    post:
      parameters:
      - in: body
        name: body
        schema:
          $ref: '#/definitions/UserCreate'      
      responses:
        201:
          description: The created user
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/UserDetail'
  /users/{id}:
    get:
      parameters:
      - in: path
        name: id
        type: string
        required: true
      responses:
        200:
          description: The user
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/UserDetail'

definitions:
  UserCreate:
    properties:
      name:
        type: string
      email:
        type: string
    example:
    - name: Bob
      email: bob@somewhere.com
  UserDetail:
    allOf:
    - $ref: '#/definitions/UserCreate'
    - properties:
        id:
          type: string
        href:
          type: string
      example:
      - id: 123
        href: /users/123
        name: Bob
        email: bob@somewhere.com
```